# Google App Engine / BigQuery log search for arbitrary string with full context

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I have enabled the Google App Engine (GAE) log export functionality, so all of my App Engine logs can be queried with Google BigQuery.

I would like to find a specific user ID in any logs in the past 7 days. I'm able to get each matching `protoPayload.line` with the snippet below, but I'm unable to show full context, i.e. all the other instances of `protoPayload.line` which came with the matching log entry.

```sql
SELECT
    metadata.timestamp AS Time,
    protoPayload.host AS Host,
    protoPayload.status AS Status,
    protoPayload.resource AS Path,
    protoPayload.line.logMessage
FROM
    (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(my_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_,
     DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    )
WHERE
    protoPayload.line.logMessage like "%My Search String%"
ORDER BY time
limit 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would write your query without TABLE_DATE_RANGE duplication. I also changed LIKE to CONTAINS for the search condition.

```
SELECT
  insertId,
  metadata.timestamp AS Time,
  protoPayload.host AS Host,
  protoPayload.status AS Status,
  protoPayload.resource AS Path,
  protoPayload.line.logMessage AS Message
  -- [add more fields here]
FROM
  TABLE_DATE_RANGE(my_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
OMIT RECORD IF
  EVERY(NOT protoPayload.line.logMessage CONTAINS "My Search String")
ORDER BY
  insertId
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 2):

After lots of digging, below is how you do full context search for the string "My Search String" in the past seven days.

Some things to note:

- You must replace `my_logs` with whatever your BigQuery dataset is called.
- You can change the number `-7` in both locations to change the date range you care about. `-8` will target the past 8 days, for example.
- You can add additional information you want returned in the outer select block by putting them above where it says `[add more fields here]`.

```sql
SELECT
  insertId,
  metadata.timestamp AS Time,
  protoPayload.host AS Host,
  protoPayload.status AS Status,
  protoPayload.resource AS Path,
  protoPayload.line.logMessage AS Message
  -- [add more fields here]
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE(my_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) )
WHERE
  insertId IN (
  SELECT
    insertId
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(my_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_, DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) )
  WHERE
    protoPayload.line.logMessage LIKE "%My Search String%" )
ORDER BY
  insertId
LIMIT 100
```

There may be a way to write the above without the strange `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` duplication, so if anyone knows, please let me know!